Why am I unable to access document fields nested inside Firebase Firestore?
I am unable to access a nested field stored in the firebase. I am deploying a cloud function written in Typescript. Here are my code snippets.
  const afterData = change.after.data();
  const productKey = afterData.items[0]?.billing_thresholds;

Here the product key value I am getting is as 'undefined'. But, I am able to access other document fields which are not nested, and get the right values.

Edited

Can you have a look at these thread1 and thread2?

Can you also try using "dot notation". i.e `afterData.items.0?.billing_thresholds;` as discussed here.

Log the value of afterData.  What does it contain?

I didnt use await keyword for a future function called. That solves it. Thanks.
